# Installing linux on unallocated partition

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, windows-8.1, partitioning

[image]

That's my HD. I want to install Elementary OS (Ubuntu based) on that unallocated partition without loosing Windows or any other partition.
I tried to make a new partition out of it in gparted but it said that you can't have more than 4 primary partitions. what should I do?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_partitioning#PC_partition_types. You'd have to deallocate/remove at least one partition adjacent to the unallocated space. This will increase the size of the unallocated space. You should then create an Extended Partition in the unallocated space. It goes without saying that you have to back up the files in the partition you're going to deallocate.

Answer (score 0):

Open Minitool Partition Editor, choose a partition **(NOT THE WINDOWS BOOT PARTITION)**, and click "Set Partition as Logical"
.
 **Do it for every partition except the windows boot partition.**
Then, **apply the changes**, and **click restart**,
Now, there will only be 2 partitions, a windows boot partition (primary partition), and a extended partition containing the rest of the partitions(Logical Partitions). So, when you install Elementary OS, use Gparted to create **another logical partition**, and you'll have **another logical partition**, but you computer will only have 2 partitions(*Windows boot* and the *Extended partition*).Sorry if this is hard to do without images.